# SFTP SSH users use from two hosts connecting same server

Tags: ssh

Can I have two SFTP SSH clients using same ssh user name but different public/private keys connect to a target server, the server has both the public keys configured?

Currently from one of the client the SFTP connectivity can be established, but the second one not able to?

Experts, please provide the solution?

Comment: Is this a theoretical question (can I) or a practical one (second client cannot connect)? If the latter, we need more details about the error(s).

Comment: Try connecting with ssh -vvv to get useful error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Yes.  You can have N public keys in `authorized_keys`; the same user can use two of them from two locations or even from just one location.

Note that even though the public key may indicate where the key was generated and for whom, that's just decoration.  Only the key itself controls whether or not it will be honored.